# Can't boot into UEFI mode on live Kubuntu usb

Tags: boot, dual-boot, kubuntu, uefi, windows-10

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 series laptop with Windows 10 on it and I am trying to install Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS alongside it. I had setup a live USB using Rufus, made all the partitions through Windows, booted into the live USB (after turning off secure boot and fast boot because the USB wouldn't appear as an option without this) and started installing it. When I got to the partitioning part, I selected one of my partitions as swap and another as ext4 journaling file system then clicked install. Then I got a message which said:

> The partition table format in use on your disks normally requires you to create a separate partition for boot loader code. This partition should be marked for us as "Reserved BIOS boot area" and should be at least 1MB in size. Note that this is not the same as a partition mounted on /boot.

I didn't really read it properly and just ignored it and continued on with the installation. Once it finished, my laptop booted back into Windows without showing me a grub or anything. So I tried manually booting into the Linux partition but that wasn't an option.

When I looked it up online, I found out that I need to boot into the USB in UEFI mode. So I tried making the live USB again through Rufus but this time using GPT as the partition scheme (instead of the MBR scheme it was on before). When I booted into the live USB I had the same issue and just to confirm that I was indeed in the BIOS version, I checked whether the file `/system/firmware/efi` existed which didn't.

I then tried using Balena Etcher to make the live USB because someone online suggested using it but I still had the same issue. I then read that if you boot into the BIOS by pressing F12 at the start, you can boot into the USB and there will be an EFI version of the USB. So I tried doing that but pressing F12 did nothing and instead just booted into Windows like normal. Note: the way I've been booting into the USB is by pressing and holding Shift while pressing restart which takes me to a Windows menu where I can boot into the USB.

I've installed Linux on a couple of laptops before using Rufus and never had a problem like this. I've tried basically everything I could find online and nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this? My main issue is trying to boot into Kubuntu in UEFI mode. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Rufus Settings for UEFI Only Ubuntu Install

Note **Partition scheme** and **Target system** for UEFI only install.

[image]

Comment: I've already tried that (UEFI was the only target system available for GPT) but here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPOLv.png) of the settings I chose just incase I missed something. As a little side note, I can only boot into the USB in DD Image Mode when I chose this partitioning scheme. The other one just gives me a blank screen, not sure if this has anything to do with it.

Comment: Have you seen this: https://www.dell.com/community/Inspiron/Kubuntu-18-04-LTS-on-Inspiron-15-7000-2-in-1/td-p/7405630 and https://gist.github.com/jaderabbit/572c3f91c7ab1424fc6d39e0e91344e9

Comment: I am a little confused why you can boot off Ubuntu USB and not off SSD? Are you sure bootloader was installed to SSD and not to USB? Are you installing in "Something else" mode?

Comment: I don't think I want to boot into the already installed version since it'd be in BIOS mode so I am trying to reinstall the whole thing. Since I can boot into Kubuntu on the live USB, do I need to try the stuff in those links?

Comment: For GRUB to work Ubuntu must be installed in the same BIOS/UEFI mode Windows is installed in. Installing in Something else with GRUB installed to OS drive, (sdx not sdx1), will not make Ubuntu install in BIOS mode. Try installing with Something else, Put boot loader on SSD, select the ext4 partition for / and check Format before trying those links.